# "Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))"

Tags: c#

I am trying to use an application, the application is working fine, i am trying to edit the existing item in the application. while clicking the edit am getting the following error,

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
  Message="Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))"
  Source="System.Windows.Forms"
  ErrorCode=-2147221164
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid& clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid)
       at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithoutLicense(Guid clsid)
       at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithLicense(String license, Guid clsid)
       at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(Guid clsid)
       at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()
       at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()
       at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32 state)
       at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
       at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.EndInit()
       at bulk_lister.frm_edititem.InitializeComponent() in New Bulklister\new bulklister\bulk_lister\bulk_lister\frm_edititem.designer.cs:line 4248
       at bulk_lister.frm_edititem..ctor(Int32 userid, Int32 intListingId) in New Bulklister\new bulklister\bulk_lister\bulk_lister\frm_edititem.cs:line 187
       at bulk_lister.parent_form.funEditItem_fromrghtclktoolStrip_edititm() in New Bulklister\new bulklister\bulk_lister\bulk_lister\parent_form.cs:line 1313
       at bulk_lister.parent_form.rghtclktoolStrip_edititm_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in New Bulklister\new bulklister\bulk_lister\bulk_lister\parent_form.cs:line 1233
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at bulk_lister.Program.Main() inNew Bulklister\new bulklister\bulk_lister\bulk_lister\Program.cs:line 17
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean checkAptModel)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly()
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Its with the Dll file that i have used with my application. i have tried to registered this dll file using regsvr32 but i cant make it.

```
DLL:AxInterop.DHTMLEDLib.dll & Interop.DHTMLEDLib.dll
```

Any one have idea on this exception?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa663363.aspx

Comment: Hans, downloading this http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8956 from your link fixed my problem that was the same. ...Thank you

Comment: how to resolved it please?

Answer (score 37):

What is the target platform of your application? I think you should set the platform to `x86`, do not set it to `Any CPU`.

Answer (score 13):

This is probably not a solution to your problem, but a suggestion just in case (I know I ran into a similar problem before but not with a .NET application).

If you are on a 64-bit machine, there are **2** `regsvr32.exe` files; 
One is in `\Windows\System32` 
and the other one is in `\Windows\SysWOW64`.

You cannot register 64-bit COM-objects with the 32-bit version, but you can do it vice versa. I'd try registering your DLL with both `regsvr32.exe` files explicitly (i.e. typing "`C:\Windows\System32\regsvr32.exe /i mydll.dll`" and then "`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe /i mydll.dll`") and seeing if that helps...

Comment: I have tryed this but am getting error"MYDll.dll was loaded but DllRegisterServer was not found"
Any Help on this?

Comment: @user1462809 calling regsvr32.exe without "/i" solved the problem for me.

Comment: Didn't help me, but I'm still wondering why they haven't named it regsvr64.exe... was it too difficult?

Answer (score 7):

I got the same error with vlc component when i changed the framework from 4.5 to 4.
but it worked for me when I changed the platform from Any CPU to x86.

Comment: This is hardly a solution. 32bit programs cannot access more than 3GB of memory.

Answer (score 5):

Something I stumbled upon today for a DLL I knew was working fine with my VS2013 project, but not with VS2015:

Go to: `Project -> XXXX Properties -> Build -> Uncheck "Prefer 32-bit"`

This answer is way overdue and probably won't do any good, but if you. But I hope this will help somebody someday.

Comment: Worked for me! I had this problem with `Microsoft.Speech.Synthesis`.

Answer (score 2):

My fix was to create Platform in configuration manager in visual studio, and set to x64

Answer (score 1):

[HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Just looking at the message it sounds like one or more of the components that you reference, or one or more of their dependencies is not registered properly.

If you know which component it is you can use regsvr32.exe to register it, just open a command prompt, go to the directory where the component is and type regsvr32 filename.dll (assuming it's a dll), if it works, try to run the code again otherwise come back here with the error.

If you don't know which component it is, try re-installing/repairing the GIS software (I assume you've installed some GIS software that includes the component you're trying to use).

Comment: i am getting this error... the module AxInterop.ShockwaveFlashObjects.dll was loaded but entry point DLLRegister server was not found. Make sure it is a valid dll or .ocx file    this dll is kept in my project bin folder.. how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to register DHTMLED.ocx

Comment: I have registered the DHTMLED.ocx, but it is not recovered the error?

Answer (score 0):

After a sequence of attempts I came into a facile solution. You can try Reinstalling ActiveX plugin for Adobe flashplayer.

Answer (score 0):

open cmd as Administrator then try to register in both location