# SSIS 2008 Class not Registered -prevented view from opening. Cannot see control flow tasks

Tags: ssis, ssrs-2008

I am trying to create and/ or install ssis packages and I get this error:

> ### TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> An error prevented the view from loading.
>
> ---
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)) (System.Windows.Forms)

---

I cannot see any control flow tasks or data flow tasks.

Comment: You need to add more information to this question for readers to be able to help you.

Comment: it's on a 2008 server.  using sql 2008 r2.  whenever I try to create a new ssis package or solution I get this error.  Or open an existing ssis package

Comment: Did you try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077477/class-not-registered-exception-from-hresult-0x80040154-regdb-e-classnotreg