# OleCreate fails with E_CLASSNOTREG when compiled with 64-Bit (C++)

Tags: c++, registry, 32bit-64bit, ole

I am trying to display a new Word document inside a Widget, using OLE. This works fine as long as I compile my application under x86 architecture. Now I tried porting my application to x64 and it stopped working. The call to `OleCreate()` fails with `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG`.

```
CLSID clsID;
IUnknown* pIUnknown;
HRESULT res = CLSIDFromProgID(L"Word.Document.8", &clsID);
if (SUCCEEDED(res)) {
   res = OleCreate(clsID, IID_IUnknown, OLERENDER_DRAW, NULL, NULL, storage, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pIUnknown));
}
```

After some research I came across some solutions, but none of them were applicable.

- I can't set my compiler to x86 when I'm trying to port my application to x64 so following [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077477/class-not-registered-exception-from-hresult-0x80040154-regdb-e-classnotreg) hasn't solved my problem.
- I tried calling `regsvr32.exe` with`C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll` but it didn't change the result.
- I tried installing the hotpatch, which was shipped by microsoft to fix the same problem with `OleCreateFromFile()`. Sadly it doesn't fix the problem for `OleCreate()` - [hotfix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2457836)

The only solution, which worked so far was to copy the content of `HKLM\SOFTWARE\SysWow64\Classes\CLSID\<CLSID of Word Document>` into `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\<CLSID of Word Document>` but this is more of a hack than a fix, because I would have to modify the registry of every machine on which I want to run my application. Since this task requires administrator privileges, I can't do this from inside my application.

I need a solution which works and doesn't force me to manually alter registry entries.

I'm running my application on  a Windows 7 Professional SP1 64-Bit machine with a 32-Bit Office 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more testing I found the solution to the problem, which was to use `Word.Document` instead of `Word.Document.8` as progID.
I have don't know why this seems to be a problem with 64-Bit compilation. The thing, I noticed though was that `CLSIDFromProgID()` now resolves to a different CLSID.