# Class not registered when I try to run setup

Tags: installation, advanced-installer

I created a setup by Advanced Installer software for my program that I've written by c#. I installed my program on VMWare Windows7.

When I try to run it this message is displayed:

[image: Class not registered]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a topic about COM registration: ["Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077477/class-not-registered-exception-from-hresult-0x80040154-regdb-e-classnotreg)

If it is a simple COM/Class registration, you should add them to COM page in your Advanced Installer project.

If you don't know what to add them to COM page you can also [use this method to register them.](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=7924#p20611)

Answer (score 0):

I used an API function in my program that checks internet connection,I think this function does not work on VmWare