# Adobe Reader COM Component Exception

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, adobe

Please offer an explanation on how the Adobe Reader works when embedded into a win form. Ideally my app's setup comes with setup for Adobe Reader XI so that it is sure to be installed when the app runs. I tried in on my PC and it worked, but running it on another PC gives the following error:

> Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click Continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. If you click Quit, the application will close immediately.
>
> Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

This error always occurs just before the form with the embedded PDF Viewer is supposed to display, so my app never makes it past this point. Is there something else I need to add to the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the target platform your application. Change Target Platform to `x86` and check.

Refer ["Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077477/class-not-registered-exception-from-hresult-0x80040154-regdb-e-classnotreg)