# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Class not registered

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-store

I add an application to the Windows store. When I download and run application, everything goes alright, but when some people download and run application, so throw the exception.

[image]

Třída není zaregistrována == Class not registered

There is code:

```
 try
 {

    StoreContext storeContext = Windows.Services.Store.StoreContext.GetDefault();
    string[] productKinds =  {"Durable", "Consumable", "UnmanagedConsumable" };
    List<String> filterList = new List<string>(productKinds);
    queryResult = await storeContext.GetAssociatedStoreProductsAsync(filterList);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
        MessageDialog(ex, "UpdateDatabaze");
   }
```

Anyone who know how I might resolve this exception?

Comment: Which app? Can I download for testing?  Can you reproduce this issue on your side?  Did you know which code line throw this exception? What's the environments of the people who got this exception? Can [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077477/class-not-registered-exception-from-hresult-0x80040154-regdb-e-classnotreg) help you?

Comment: Thanks you, but I solved this problem. For a minutes I write the solution. It is really simple :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am programming the application with target version Windows anniversary (build version 14393), which supports StoreContext class. When users download application and their Windows was not anniversary but only windows 10 with build 10586 or lowest build version, then throw exception which is described in the part called question.