# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID error: 80040154 Class not registered Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG

Tags: c#, wpf, access-database-engine

am running wpf application on 64bit cpu machine, with .net 4.6.1, 64bit AccessDatabaseEngine 2010.

the configurations are:
Build > configuration manager > active solution platform: any cpu
project settings > Build > platform: any cpu, platform target: x64

someone please suggest solution

Comment: Did you try a web search?, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077477/class-not-registered-exception-from-hresult-0x80040154-regdb-e-classnotreg